# Populate an array with another array

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object

I have made a trigger that populates one object from another, it only works for one item now.  I'm stuck because I have two lists one populated and one not populated  and I want to populate the second one with the first one using for loop. Here is what the trigger looks like. The for loop at the end is where i want to populate the listQS2 from the values from NSproductlist

```
/* if triggered from a batch upload there could be multiple items in the set**/

List<Quote> quoteTemp = Trigger.new;

System.debug('number of items in ID set ' + quoteTemp.size());
System.debug(quoteTemp[0].OpportunityId);


List<QS_Product_1__c> NSproductlist = new List<QS_Product_1__c>([SELECT ID,
                                                                        Name,  
                                                                        Price__c, 
                                                                        Quantity__c, 
                                                                        Sales_Price__c, 
                                                                        Opportunity_QS__c 
                                                                   From QS_Product_1__c  
                                                                  WHERE Opportunity_QS__C = :quoteTemp[0].OpportunityId] );
List<QS_Product_2__c> listQS2 = new List<QS_Product_2__c>();

System.debug('David' + NSproductlist.size());
System.debug('lineitem1: ' + NSproductlist[0] );


for(QS_Product_1__c temp : NSproductlist){

    QS_Product_2__c productQ2 = new QS_Product_2__c();
    productQ2.Name = NSproductlist[0].Name;
    productQ2.Price__c = NSproductlist[0].Price__c;
    productQ2.Quote_QS__c=quoteTemp[0].id;     
}
```

Merry christmas!!

Here is what I'm trying out now :

```
for(QS_Product_1__c temp : NSproductlist){
        listQS2[0].Name = temp.Name;
        listQS2[0].price__c = temp.price__c;
        listQS2[0].Quote_QS__c = temp.id;
      //  QS_Product_2__c productQ2 = new QS_Product_2__c();
      //  productQ2.Name = NSproductlist[index].Name;
      //  productQ2.Price__c = NSproductlist[index].Price__c;
      //  productQ2.Quote_QS__c=quoteTemp[index].id; 
      System.debug('index is :' + index);    
        //index ++;
    }
    insert listQS2;
```

Comment: Your query for `QS_Product_1__c` filters on just the first item of `Trigger.new`. You will probably want to loop over `Trigger.new` first and get all of the opportunity ids from them, so you can query for all of them.

Comment: Yes you're right, but i want to concentrate on the bottom part of the code so i can populate the list with another already populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is not completed but guessing This will solve your issue.

```
for(QS_Product_1__c temp : NSproductlist){

    QS_Product_2__c productQ2 = new QS_Product_2__c();
    productQ2.Name = temp.Name;
    productQ2.Price__c = temp.Price__c;
    productQ2.Quote_QS__c= temp.id;    
    //add  productQ2  into a list for other operation
}
```

---

**Edit** based on above code

```
List<QS_Product_2__c> listQS2 = new List<QS_Product_2__c>();

for(QS_Product_1__c temp : NSproductlist){

    QS_Product_2__c productQ2 = new QS_Product_2__c();
    productQ2.Name = temp.Name;
    productQ2.Price__c = temp.Price__c;
    productQ2.Quote_QS__c= temp.id;
    listQS2.add(productQ2); 
}
insert listQS2;
```

Comment: We're trying to avoid inserting individual records inside of the for loop. So we need to build an array of records and do a single insert  outside of the loop

Comment: Yes @Greg correct.

Comment: I've made an edit with what I'm trying out now.

Comment: @Greg one question if `NSproductlist` contains 2 records then how many `productQ2` record should create?

Comment: The same amount of records as in NS Product 2. and then stop when there is no more records

Comment: @Greg check my **Edit** in above ans